# R-hub package checks stall at 'Preparing build'

Tags: r, package, devtools

I'm trying to build my first R package and running into an issue trying to check on multiple OS configurations with [R-hub](https://builder.r-hub.io/). Specifically, I am calling `devtools::check_rhub()` with the default configuration, but everything stalls out with the message, "Preparing build, see status at..."

[image: Rstudio console]

It will linger at this stage for hours if I leave it alone. If I go to those links where I am supposed to be able to see the status, it is just blank:
[image: website with nothing happening]

On the website, it says 'Email not verified' so I thought that was the problem, but using `rhub::validate_email()` indicates that my email is validated.

I think it is an `rhub`, not `devtools`, issue because the same thing happens if I call `rhub::check()` directly.

Here is the package: https://github.com/samzipper/streamdepletr

It passes all checks locally on my Windows machine (`devtools::check()`), on travis-ci, and on the R win-builder platform (`devtools::check_win()`)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the email validation, because the `rhub` package would not let you submit the package. The "email not validated" part of the webform stays until you submit from there, because with the webform you can only validate the email when uploading the package.

Are the builds still hanging? I suspect there was too much activity on the servers (but can't check my assumption :-) ).

For info here are other ways to get help with R-hub https://docs.r-hub.io/#pkg-dev-help (the R-hub team does not regularly check Stack Overflow). Disclaimer: I am a contributor to R-hub docs.

Comment: Hi Maëlle, please disclose your affiliation ... btw. overdoing might get a problem even though you disclosured.

Comment: Thanks @MaëlleSalmon - I retried this morning and it is still hanging. I will post on one of the resources you suggest.